# Pipeline is stuck on "pending"

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using GitLab's shared CI runners for training. Since this morning I can't build
my project because the pipeline's status is "pending".

Is it because the number of shared runners is maxed out ? Too busy running other people's
code ?

Is there a setting I need to check ? I know I can pay for a dedicated runner but I'm not
in commercial setting at this point therefore I'm sticking with shared ones.

Thank you for assistance.

Comment: can you please check if pipeline is waiting for some resource? The default timeout is set to 1 hr so it should be failed by now. Can you please check and share the logs and update above?

Comment: @ArihantGodha  It is running now again. From the looks of it I just had to wait as shared runners are used by many for training.

Answer (score 1):

In such situations I would highly recommend to make the best use of `tags`. You can use tags to select a specific runner from the list of all runners that are available for the project.

In this example, the job is run by a runner that
has both `ruby` and `postgres` tags defined.

```
job:
  tags:
    - ruby
    - postgres
```

If you have your own runners setup then you can use tags to run different jobs on different platforms. For
example, if you have an OS X runner with tag `osx` and a Windows runner with tag
`windows`, you can run a job on each platform:

```
windows job:
  stage:
    - build
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - echo Hello, %USERNAME%!

osx job:
  stage:
    - build
  tags:
    - osx
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $USER!"
```

If this is still a problem then consider using your own private runner.